# Xamarin form: Is it normal to have different screen for different viewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have numerous of content pages for the application and ending up written lot of view model of each content page. Eg. if I have a list with groups of items I would have a `ShowAllViewModel` and bind to the content page and a view model for individual item in the list.

In `ShowAllViewModel`, I would have functions related to the content page whereas the view model for the item will have properties or function to be displayed in the list.

Is this the normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a nice approach to writing a MVVM-based application. A `ViewModel` is basically abstracting the logic from a view and it can on itself also manage other sub-`ViewModels`, that are data bound to other controls on the same page.

Giving each item in the list its own `ViewModel` is beneficial, beacuse it can work as a self contained unit, which has its own data-bound properties, its own commands, etc., while the parent `ViewModel` manages the list itself.

In MVVM apps you often end up creating small `ViewModel` wrappers for many of your data models, which is a good thing, because you create an abstraction layer that allows you to expose the properties and values you actually need or convert the model properties to the right format for presentation.

Comment: Thanks .. I also found it easier to manage and logically easier compare with my first created application. Even though the first can work but hard to manage.